# make not recognizing opam installed ocamlfind

Tags: linux, installation, package-management, make, apt

I'm trying to run `make` involving a dependency on `ocamlfind` but when I try to install that, it gives me a circular dependency and a dependency on `ocaml-base-nox`.

I figured out that I could get `ocaml-findlib` and `libfindlib-ocaml` which depend on each other to install at the same time with one command:
`sudo apt install ocaml-findlib ocaml-findlib libfindlib-ocaml ocaml-base-nox-4.01.0`
However, the remaining dependency returns `Package 'ocaml-base-nox-4.01.0' has no installation candidate`. It does mention a couple packages, apparently:

```
Package ocaml-base-nox-4.01.0 is a virtual package provided by:
  ocaml-base-nox 4.01.0-3ubuntu3.1 [Not candidate version]
  ocaml-base-nox 4.01.0-3ubuntu3 [Not candidate version]
```

An answer helping make progress on getting that package installed may be helpful. Otherwise, one revealing to me how to get make to recognize the `opam` installed instance may help. As you can see, that installation actually worked:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/projectfolder$ opam list
# Installed packages for system:
base-bigarray   base  Bigarray library distributed with the OCaml compiler
base-threads    base  Threads library distributed with the OCaml compiler
base-unix       base  Unix library distributed with the OCaml compiler
conf-m4            1  Virtual package relying on m4
ocamlfind      1.7.3  A library manager for OCaml
```

As you can see, I was able to successfully install ocamlfind via opam.
Interestingly, my make command doesn't seem to recognize `ocamlfind` which I added to the environment when installing with `opam`:

```
/path/to/some/folder/which/is/super/secret -O2 -d acommand file.f
[Error] Critical: Error starting ocamlopt process: Cannot run program
"ocamlfind" (in directory
"/path/to/some/folder/."): error=2, No such file
or directory (Cannot run program "ocamlfind" (in directory
"/path/to/some/folder/."): error=2, No such file
or directory)
make: *** [some/folder/timestamp] Error 113
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs because your environment variables were not set up correctly. In order to do that, it should be enough to run the following command:

```
eval `opam config env`
```

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this. I've been using a Virtual Box Ubuntu since then and I haven't been messing with OCaml. I'm not sure if I solved the problem by doing this or not. I suppose of you're sure that this is the typical solution, I'll select it as the most useful answer, especially since other answers don't exist.